# modx 1.05 - how to remove new lines on Ditto's call

Tags: php, modx, ditto

when I'm calling in the item tpl a piece of content by:

```
<p>[+content:len:gt=`100`:then=`[+content:character_limit=`100`+]`:else=`[+content+]`+]</p>
```

there are new-lines (BR or \n\r) from tinymce. I want to remove them - how can I do that?

Comment: You could use a phx to remove unwanted characters before `:character_limit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *quickest* way to avoid TinyMCE formatting things like this is to place them in a chunk or template variable (from personal experience).

Edit: You can also take a look at the TinyMCE plugin configuration under:

> Elements > Manage Elements > Plugins (tab) > TinyMCE Rich Text Editor

You can enter custom TinyMCE parameters in the *Custom Parameters* textarea. Take a look at http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#TinyMCE_adds_BR_elements_to_my_content

Comment: hmmm avoiding text formatting in tinymce is not the solution for me. But thanks for suggestion. I'll try put the alternative content without new-lines to the special tv (template variable)

Comment: You can still have TinyMCE format your content etc, just move any parts it is not handling correctly outside of it (to a chunk for example).